# Laravel 5 Query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I tried advanced where clauses

i have model with 2 datetime columns `start` and `end`

the request comes two values `date_start, date_end`

my code

```
->where(function($q) use ($date_start,$date_end) {
                $q->where('start','>=',$date_start)
                  ->where('end','<=',$date_start)
                  ->where('start','>=',$date_end)
                  ->where('end','<=',$date_end);
            })
            ->first();
```

code returned nothing but in table have one record,
values on request suitable. What is wrong?

Comment: What is the records start and end value and what start and end value are you passing in to compare against?

Comment: What do you expect from that condition? I think it can only match the condition if your record, in database, has start date >= end date and $date_start and $date_end is within [end, start]

Comment: If you are comparing dates, you might want to use `whereDate`

Answer (score 0):

worked

```
$q->where('start','<=',$date_start)
  ->where('start','<',$date_end)
  ->where('end','<=',$date_end);
```